# Locust performance graping solutions

Tags: performance, graph, grafana, snapshot, locust

I've created a locust script to hit our most popular end points. I am wanting to do advance graphing since currently the default locust graphing is minimal. For example, maybe show a trend of a graph showing each end point of the average ms from low to high after a certain amount of requests for each snapshot. I browsed and it seems grafana and some plugsin might be the way to go? If there's other options please advice I would love any ideas or things to explore. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your question isnt 100% clear but yes `locust-plugins` Timescale/Grafana dashboards is probably the way to go for more advanced graphing/analysis.
https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/tree/master/locust_plugins/dashboards